# <apex:inputField> won't allow edit

Tags: visualforce

I have 4 columns and Input Fields to edit a list of data. The data shows up fine, but only 2 of the columns have an editable field.  What am I doing wrong, as each column is coded the same.  Thanks in advance.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(accounts))}">
   <apex:column >
     <apex:facet name="header">ISO Account</apex:facet>
     <apex:inputField value="{!a.Account__r.name}" onchange="updateRecords();"></apex:inputField>
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column >
     <apex:facet name="header">RM Rank</apex:facet>
     <apex:inputField value="{!a.RM_Rank__c}" onchange="updateRecords();"></apex:inputField>
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column >
     <apex:facet name="header">Relationship Manager</apex:facet>
     <apex:inputField value="{!a.Relationship_Manager_Contact__r.name}" onchange="updateRecords();"></apex:inputField>
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column >
     <apex:facet name="header">Recruiter</apex:facet>
     <apex:inputField value="{!a.Recruiter__r.name}" onchange="updateRecords();"></apex:inputField>
   </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Can't edit cross object. You can only edit fields on the `Account` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not want the Name field of the related records, that would be editing the records themselves. I assume you want to input the lookup relationship. In that case you want to use what would be the Id field of the lookup. In your first field, it is most likely Account__c. If you are using inputField, Visualforce will convert the value to the name of the object and add the lookup search functionality.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now.  Not the first time I did something like that with this object.  The query for the search is written like the above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Three of these fields are related fields. Depending on the relationship, You can't generally edit related fields.

To edit a related field, you'd normally put it in an `<apex:inputText>` and handle the save of the related record in the controller.